# What should I put in a method that receives an Activity as a parameter?

Tags: java, android

Here is my method which needs an Activity as a parameter.

```
 public  View getContentView(Activity ac){
            ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup)ac.getWindow().getDecorView();
            FrameLayout content = (FrameLayout)view.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
            return content.getChildAt(0);
        }
```

When  putting  `OneActivity.class` or `OneActivity.this` , it meets with error:
getContentView(android.app.Activity) in MainActivity cannot be applied to (java.lang.Class).

```
oneView=getContentView();
```

my whole code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    private View oneView;
    private View twoView;
    private View threeView;
    private ArrayList<View> views;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        views = new ArrayList<View>();
        mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager_main);
        initView();
        addViews();

        PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter() {

            @Override
            public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
                return arg0 == arg1;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return views.size();
            }

        };

        mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    }

    /**
     * convert  acitivity to corresponding view
     */
    public void initView(){

        oneView=getContentView(OneActivity);
        twoView=getContentView(TwoActivity);
        threeView=getContentView(ThreeActivity);
    }



    /**
     * add views into list
     */
    public void addViews(){

        views.add(oneView);
        views.add(twoView);
        views.add(threeView);
    }

    public  View getContentView(Activity ac){
        ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup)ac.getWindow().getDecorView();
        FrameLayout content = (FrameLayout)view.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        return content.getChildAt(0);
    }

}
```

My idea is to use ViewPager to implement sideslipping to switch Activity.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

It won't work with .class, you need an instance.  .this only works if you call it from OneActivity.  I honestly question why you need this-  if you're in the activity itself, there's easier ways of doing it (save it off after inflation and pass it where needed).  If you're not in the Activity, then you shouldn't be touching that Activity's views anyway.

Comment: I think I'd better try something else. Anyway, thank you

Answer (score 0):

try using Context instead of activity

```
public  View getContentView(Context mContext){

            // cast mContext to Your Activity
            ActivityName mActivity = (ActivityName) mContext;

            // call your desired methods below
            ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) mActivity.getWindow().getDecorView();
            FrameLayout content = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
            return content.getChildAt(0);

        }
```

Comment: No, If so, what do you put in?

Comment: just pass **this**

Comment: Hope it helped !!